# Exportar e Importar BD de PhpMyadmin

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, xampp, mariadb

Anteriormente había trabajado sin problema la creación desde consola de la BD y sin problema exportaba e importaba, pero ahora cuando intento importar la BD que ya exporté con anterioridad me salen errores de sentencia. Encontré que puede ser por la versión de UTF pero ya lo he revisado y sigo con el mismo problema.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Edita o mira el contenido del archivo .SQL que intentas importar. Tiene toda la pinta que fue exportado mal, dando algun tipo de error en formato HTML y guardándose como si fuera el archivo exportado, y por eso ahora se queja durante la importación, pues está encontrando una página HTML en lugar de comandos SQL.  Si tengo razón deberás buscar otra exportación que sí haya funcionado, pues con esta no podrás hacer nada. Revisa ese HTML pues seguramente te indica el error que tuviste durante la exportación.

Comment: @masterguru de hecho si intenté exportarlo en extensión csv y me lo exportó normal, lo que me comentaron es que quizá el puerto se dañó e hizo que el servicio de mysql no se ejecutara bien y toca reinstalar o ver que fue lo que le hizo que se dañara.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La única solución que pude darle es volver a instalar XAMPP y configurar los puertos a modo que queden bien identificados.